# war Ant task with needxmlfile="false" still complains

Tags: ant, web.xml

I have the following **war** task in my **build.xml** and even though *needxmlfile* is set to *false*, **Ant** (version 1.8.2) complains when the *web.xml* file does not exist ("*BUILD FAILED ... Deployment descriptor: /home/.../web/WEB-INF/web.xml does not exist*")

What am I missing?

```
  <target name="war" depends="build">                                                                           
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>                                                                                 
    <war                                                                                                        
      needxmlfile="false"                                                                                       
      basedir="${webroot.dir}"                                                                                  
      warfile="${build.dir}/${project.distname}.war"                                                            
      webxml="${webinf.dir}/web.xml">                                                                           
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/${build.dir}/**"/>                                                                 
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/src/**"/>                                                                          
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>                                                                         
     </war>                                                                                                     
  </target>
```

Comment: Why specify the "webxml" attribute, if the file doesn't exist? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: The reason I had for this particular case was to use the same Ant build file template for a number of web projects, some of which did not need a web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@O'Connor: thanks for the hint for using a fileset to pull the web.xml. However I am not sure you are correct about the needxmlfile set to true (at least in my experimentation I witnessed the opposite of what you describe). In any case, in the end I realized that not even the fileset is necessary since the **war** Ant task apparently packages everything under the **basedir** (unless explicitly excluded) so I am now using the following war task that works whether a **web.xml** file is present or not:

```
<target name="war" depends="build">                                                                      
   <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>                                                                            
   <war                                                                                                   
      needxmlfile="false"                                                                                  
      basedir="${webroot.dir}"                                                                             
      destfile="${build.dir}/${project.distname}.war">                                                      
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/${build.dir}/**"/>                                                            
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/src/**"/>                                                                     
    </war>                                                                                                
</target>
```

Setting needxmlfile to "true" causes Ant to complain if no web.xml file can be found during "waring".

Answer (score 1):

The [ANT documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) states that the **webxml** attribute is mandatory unless the  **needxmlfile** attribute is set to *true*

Try this and use a fileset to pull in the optional web.xml file.